# Power output of a heat engine

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, heat-engine

The thermodynamic cycle of a heat engine is shown. The shape of the curve is elliptical with one axis parallel to the S-axis. This cycle is executed 20 cycles/s. The power output of the engine is nearest to 
$a) 12.5\,\,b)32\,\,c)2.5\,\, d)10\,\,e) 58 $ (all in kW)

[image]

Attempt:

W(work) = $|Q_h|-|Q_l|$

$Q_h = T_h\Delta S= 500*25=12500J$

$Q_l = T_l\Delta S= 300*15=4500 J$
W = $8000J$

P(Power) = $ 8000/20 = 400 W$* As pointed out in the comments, going by the units 
it should be $8000*20 = 160kW$ Yet this is still way off from the given options.
I wonder if this is  how it is to be done?

Comment: We generally aren't a "check my work" site.  That said, check your units.  $\frac{8000 \frac {J}{Cycle} }{20 \frac {Cycle}{second}} = 400 \frac {J \ s}{cycle^2}$ is what you have actually shown.

Comment: Well, I do know that but I have no answers to refer to and no peers so hence I try to get help from here . As per what you have said, even if i do multiply, 160kW is no where near to any of the options. Wondering if this is how its done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The heats should be 500x10 and 300x10, so the difference is 2000 Joules per cycle.  More accurately, the area of an ellipse is $\pi ab$ where a is the semi-major axis and b is the semi-minor axis.  So, in this case, the work per cycle would be $\pi (100)(5)$ Joules.

Comment: work per cycle is $ pi (200) (10) $ you mean?

Comment: No.  What do the words semi-major and semi-minor mean to you?

Comment: To me Semi major in this case is 25-15 isn't it? the longest diameter and semi minor is  500-300, the shorter one. isn't it?

Comment: Semi major is half the major axis, and semi minor is half the minor axis.  The equation for the area of an ellipse has to reduce to that of a circle $\pi r^2$ when the major and minor axes are equal.

Comment: Oh yes indeed!, Thanks a lot. I often make such trivial mistakes.